# Full Text Search Prefix Search problems

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have a SQL Server 2012 Installation and few Full Text indexed columns.
Now i few full text indexed columns where I am doing a `CONTAINS()` search.

So my table has there kinds of data

> "393033-H-X02.1", "393033-H-X03.1", "393033-J-X02.1",
>   "393033-J-X03.1", "393033-J-X04.1"

**Q1** - Now when I do a search like this, I do not get any data ( NOTE THE STAR AT THE END).

```
SELECT * FROM tblMyData where MyFullTextCoulm CONTAINS ('"393033-H-X02.1*"')
```

**Q2** - Now when i do a search like this, I GET my any data, but it return "393033-J-X02.1" as well

```
SELECT * FROM tblMyData where MyFullTextCoulm CONTAINS ('"393033-H-X02.1"')
```

I have been reading through the documentation and I know about the **PREFIX** Search in **SQLServer full text** but it dose not co-relate to what I see.

I just need to find rows where i can find that exact word in any place in that column, have tried the **LIKE** operator which is very slow.

Any kind of help/suggestion is appreciated,

Comment: How come `LIKE` become slow if you filter ? , how many data do you have in your table   ?

Comment: More than 10 Million

Comment: Oh i see , did you put proper index ?

Comment: Yes may properly though through Indexes are there, LIKE is not exactly slow but way slower than the CONTAINS and slower than our acceptance of 100 mill sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a [stoplist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx) in your full text index and this is causing the problem. If you configure your full text index to not use a stoplist and then rebuild the index, your queries will produce the results that you expect.

How is the stoplist affecting your queries? First, some background. A string such as `393033-H-X02.1` is broken apart into separate strings when indexed, for example: `393033` + `H` + `X02` + `1`. So when you search on `'"393033-H-X02.1"'`, you're actually searching across multiple words just like if you searched `'"this is a sentence"'`.

Your stoplist is excluding single letters (`H`) and single digits (`1`). These words get ignored during full text searches, so `'"393033-H-X02.1"'` is like searching `'"393033-*-X02.*"'`, where `*` matches only stopwords. This is why, per your Q2, you get additional results you were not expecting when searching for `'"393033-H-X02.1"'`, because the full text search engine is matching `H` with `J` since they are both stopwords.

Your Q1 is a little trickier for to explain. For reasons I've never understood, a full text search across multiple strings which include stopwords and a wildcard can sometimes yield unpredictable results. This is what's happening when you search for `'"393033-H-X02.1*"'`. I wish I could explain it better but I just don't know the exact causes. However, disabling the stoplist will prevent this problem from happening.

Comment: thanks for that, forgot to read the fine-print of 'Rebuilding the index'. Works great now